# Professor sent a letter of recommendation meant for one school to a different school

Tags: graduate-school, masters, recommendation-letter

My professor mistakenly sent a letter of recommendation meant for one school to another school. What is going to happen to the letter and my chances of getting in?

Comment: Have the professor email the admissions office and ask what to do.  The correct letter could even be attached to the email.

Comment: Has the professor tailored their letter to the school, such as mentioning faculty members or research groups by name?

Answer (score 2):

Elin, in a comment above, makes the right recommendation for what action to take at this point: the professor should email the admissions office and ask what to do, perhaps with the correct letter attached.  But even if you and your professor do nothing, this most likely won't matter.  Probably the only difference in the letters is one line at the top identifying the recipient; all of the important content, namely what the professor has to say about you, will be the same.

So what is going to happen, most likely, is that admissions committee at the school you're applying to will look at the letter, chuckle a bit at your professor's oversight (which they will in no way see as reflecting on you), and move on to reading the important part of the letter.  They're not going to throw away the letter because of it, and your chances of getting in shouldn't be affected at all.

Good luck with your applications!